# ScrollView messing up child element animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

On occasion, whatever default animation exists in the still limited `ScrollView` in Swift UI, leads to a "compounding" animation effect.

```swift
ScrollView {
   Text("Hello")
      .animation(
         Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 200, damping: 3)
      )
}
```

This can, sometimes, lead to a much stronger spring effect (with respect to the `offset`) on initial load as the `ScrollView` gets rendered.

Is there a way to isolate the spring effect to the offset relative to itself rather than its absolute offset.

> As interesting note is that if I turn the `ScrollView` into `VStack` this doesn't happen. It seem`ScrollView` has some animation on initial render.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here's a hack for anyone desperate:

```swift
struct Hack: View {
  @State var show = false

  public var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      Text("Hello")
        .animation(
          Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 200, damping: 3)
        )
        .opacity(show ? 1 : 0) // this is the hack
        .onAppear { self.show.toggle() }
    }
  }
}
```

This will disable the egregious (at least in my case) animation on the initial load. This really isn't a good answer nor an insight into whats happening with `ScrollView`.